# Creating a post/comment ability in Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-models, django-views

I'm going to write a post/comment function in Django with models and views.
I need a good example and tutorial.
Or I need an example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/